# Compiling error for a function call, Arduino

Tags: arduino

I have a problem when I compile my program. It is written like this:

```
 AP_Var(AP_Var_group *group, Key index, const prog_char_t *name, Flags flags = k_flags_none);
```

The compiler tells me that

`AP_Var.h:163: error: expected ',' or '...' before '*' token`

To what I know, `prog_char_t` comes from another file called `Betterstream.h`, but what exactly is `prog_char_t`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prog_char_t` is defined as follows in [`AP_Common.h`](http://www.google.com/codesearch#lY0wEzJTcVk/trunk/libraries/AP_Common/AP_Common.h) in the [Arducopter](http://code.google.com/p/arducopter/) source.

```
// prog_char_t is used as a wrapper type for prog_char, which is
// a character stored in flash. By using this wrapper type we can
// auto-detect at compile time if a call to a string function is using
// a flash-stored string or not
typedef struct {
        char c;
} prog_char_t;
```

i.e. it defines a `char` which is stored in the program memory of an AVR microcontroller.

The standard Arduino environment uses [avr-libc](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/) which defines [`prog_char`](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__pgmspace.html#gaa475b6b81fd8b34de45695da1da523b6) for the same purpose. It's not clear to me why the [Arducopter](http://code.google.com/p/arducopter/) team chose to define this themselves.

Comment: Oh i see. So prog_char_t is like int or float or char? It is used to define a declaration?

Comment: Yes, it's a custom type defined within the Arducopter source code.